# Find the splitting field of $x^m-1\in\Bbb F_p$.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, proof-explanation, extension-field, splitting-field

It is an exercise in Milne's notes. But I don't think I understand the solution...

Here is the solution:

[image: It seems that Milne does not give the]

It seems that Milne does not give the justification. So may I please ask for a proof? Or any reference would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a finite field and an extension of $\Bbb F_p$ so it is
$\Bbb F_{p^k}$ for some $k$. The $m$-th roots of $1$ are the $m_0$-th roots
of $1$ and there are $m_0$ of them. The multiplicative group of $\Bbb F_{p^k}$ contains all $m_0$ of them iff $m_0\mid(p^k-1)$, as the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic. So the smallest $k$
that works is the least $k>0$ with $p^k\equiv1\pmod{m_0}$.

Comment: I am quite confused that he does not give a definition of $m_0$. Could you please tell me how does $m_0$ defined?

Comment: @non-abeliangroupoforder9 Your quotation from Milne contains a definition of $m_0$.

Comment: Sorry I cannot find the definition clearly. It seems that he use it directly without define it...

Comment: Or is it the fact that $m_0$ is simplely defined to be any number which divides $p^n-1$?

Comment: "$m=m_0p^r$ where $p$ is prime and does not divide $m_0$" defines $m_0$.

Comment: I am confused. Does he mean that $p$ is redefined? I think the $p$ is already fixed in the question. But now he seems to mean that "let p be a prime such that"...

Comment: And also, what is $r$?

Comment: "$m=m_0p^r$ where $p$ is prime and does not divide $m_0$" defines $r$.

Comment: Sorry but the confusion persists... It seems that he defines $m_0, r,n$ all together. May I please ask what do we choose firstly, and depend on it we define the second one?

Comment: @non-abeliangroupoforder9 Please think about this. If $m\in\Bbb N$ and $p$ is a prime, then there are unique $m_0\in\Bbb N$ and $r\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$ with $m=m_0p^r$. This really isn't a big deal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought for a while and still cannot see why the m-th root of unity are $m_0$-th root of unity. It makes some sence but maybe there is something subtle. I don't think that we have $x^p=1$ so the $p$'s are cancelled out. May I please ask for some more explicit explaination here?

Comment: Thanks so much. After some thinking I think I get what you mean...